# How to use dynamic router links with method

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 7 app.
In this app I got a set of links. When the page loads the getRouterURL fires for each of the links (and everytime I click one of the links all fire the method. Is this the correct behaviour? It feels like a waste of memory?

```
<a [routerLink]="getRouterURL('normal')">Link</a>
<a [routerLink]="getRouterURL('normal')">Link 2</a>
<a [routerLink]="getRouterURL('page')">Link 3</a>
<a [routerLink]="getRouterURL('page')">Link 4</a>
```

The method looks like this.

```
getRouterURL(type) {
  console.log('Method fired');
  if (type === 'normal') {
    return 'normal' + this.proposalId + '/' + model.id;
  } else {
    return 'pages' + this.proposalId + '/' + model.id;
  }

}
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: what exactly is getRouterURL doing?

Comment: Returning the url based upon the model type.

Comment: You can use `[routerLink]="..."` when you want to build a dynamic url, e.g., `[routerLink]="['a', 'b', some_var_id]"`

Comment: Could you first make the call, then store it in a variable, then do a for loop over the `a` and inisde the `[routerLink]` use the stored route??

Comment: Each link can either be of type normal or type page. So it need to be reflected in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. Angular has no way of knowing if that binding has changed. It can only know it by executing the function again. That's why it's usually better to limit the amount of function call bindings from inside your template. You can either solve this by using an `@Input()` which somehow sets the data, or even better, by using a pure `@Pipe`

Comment: So it does not matter if the method fires many times? It is very simple so I guess not?

Comment: @JonathanClark It shouldn't matter with a function like this, but be sparse with them, and don't put a lot of logic in them. Better cache it, or use a pipe :)